# Llamar método de Botones

Tags: java

Tengo un problema estoy desarrollando un juego de encontrar objetos en java. Lo que pasa es que los botones (en este caso 5) van a quedar en blanco después de que el jugador termine de encontrar todos los objetos.

Lo que quiero es que cuando esos 5 objetos lleguen a blanco aparezca un mensaje de que ganaste, pero no entiendo como llamar esos 5 botones, para que cuando los 5 estén ya en blanco salga el mensaje alguien me puede ayudar ? gracias

```
public class Ventana extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private boolean estado;
private int contar;
private String nombre;

/**
 * Creates new form Ventana
 */
public Ventana() {
    initComponents();

}


private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    estado = false;
    Inicio();
    Mensaje();
}                                 

private void jButton6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    estado = true;
    Inicio();
    jButton6.setVisible(false);
    jButton1.setText("Pecera");
    jButton2.setText("Cartas");
    jButton3.setText("Tijeras");
    jButton4.setText("Oso");
    jButton5.setText("Candado");
}                                     

private void peceraMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    if (jButton1.getText().equals("Pecera") || jButton2.getText().equals("Pecera") || jButton3.getText().equals("Pecera") || jButton4.getText().equals("Pecera") || jButton5.getText().equals("Pecera")) {
        this.pecera.setVisible(false);
        this.nombre = "Pecera";
        this.CleanBoton();
        this.contar += 10;
       puntaje.setText("puntos: "+contar);
    }
}                                   

private void cartaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    if (jButton1.getText().equals("Cartas") || jButton2.getText().equals("Cartas") || jButton3.getText().equals("Cartas") || jButton4.getText().equals("Cartas") || jButton5.getText().equals("Cartas")) {
        carta.setVisible(false);
        nombre = "Cartas";
        CleanBoton();
        contar += 10;
        puntaje.setText("puntos: "+contar);
    }
}                                  

private void tijeraMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    if (jButton1.getText().equals("Tijeras") || jButton2.getText().equals("Tijeras") || jButton3.getText().equals("Tijeras") || jButton4.getText().equals("Tijeras") || jButton5.getText().equals("Tijeras")) {
        tijera.setVisible(false);
        nombre = "Tijeras";
        CleanBoton();
        contar += 10;
        puntaje.setText("puntos: "+contar);
    }
}                                   

private void candadoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if (jButton1.getText().equals("Candado") || jButton2.getText().equals("Candado") || jButton3.getText().equals("Candado") || jButton4.getText().equals("Candado") || jButton5.getText().equals("Candado")) {
        candado.setVisible(false);
        nombre = "Candado";
        CleanBoton();
        contar += 10;
        puntaje.setText("puntos: "+contar);
    }
}                                    

private void osoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
    if (jButton1.getText().equals("Oso") || jButton2.getText().equals("Oso") || jButton3.getText().equals("Oso") || jButton4.getText().equals("Oso") || jButton5.getText().equals("Oso")) {
        oso.setVisible(false);
        nombre = "Oso";
        CleanBoton();
        contar += 10;
        puntaje.setText("puntos: "+contar);
    }
}                                

private void pilaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
    if (jButton1.getText().equals("Pila") || jButton2.getText().equals("Pila") || jButton3.getText().equals("Pila") || jButton4.getText().equals("Pila") || jButton5.getText().equals("Pila")) {
        pila.setVisible(false);

        nombre = "Pila";

        jButton1.setText(" ");
        contar += 10;
        puntaje.setText("puntos: "+contar);
    }
}                                 

private void gatoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
    if (jButton1.getText().equals("Gato") || jButton2.getText().equals("Gato") || jButton3.getText().equals("Gato") || jButton4.getText().equals("Gato") || jButton5.getText().equals("Gato")) {
        gato.setVisible(false);

        nombre = "Gato";

        jButton2.setText(" ");
        contar += 10;
        puntaje.setText("puntos: "+contar);
    }
}                                 

private void pantalonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    if (jButton1.getText().equals("Pantalon") || jButton2.getText().equals("Pantalon") || jButton3.getText().equals("Pantalon") || jButton4.getText().equals("Pantalon") || jButton5.getText().equals("Pantalon")) {
        pantalon.setVisible(false); 
        nombre = "Pantalon";
        jButton3.setText(" ");
        contar += 10;
        puntaje.setText("puntos: "+contar);
    }
}                                     

private void lavadoraMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    if (jButton1.getText().equals("Lavadora") || jButton2.getText().equals("Lavadora") || jButton3.getText().equals("Lavadora") || jButton4.getText().equals("Lavadora") || jButton5.getText().equals("Lavadora")) {
        lavadora.setVisible(false);

        nombre = "Lavadora"; 
       jButton4.setText(" ");
        contar += 10;
        puntaje.setText("puntos: "+contar);
    }
}                                     

private void jabonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    if (jButton1.getText().equals("Jabon") || jButton2.getText().equals("Jabon") || jButton3.getText().equals("Jabon") || jButton4.getText().equals("Jabon") || jButton5.getText().equals("Jabon")) {
        jabon.setVisible(false);

        nombre = "Jabon";

         jButton5.setText(" ");
        contar += 10;
        puntaje.setText("puntos: "+contar);
    }
}                                  

private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}                                        

private void jButton7MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    Niveles ni = new Niveles();
    ni.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}                                     

private void puntajeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                    

private void Inicio() {
    reloj.setVisible(estado);
    globo.setVisible(estado);
    pajaro.setVisible(estado);
    avion.setVisible(estado);
    estrella.setVisible(estado);
    cuadro.setVisible(estado);
    espejo.setVisible(estado);
    mono.setVisible(estado);
    puerta.setVisible(estado);
    encendedor.setVisible(estado);
    escalera.setVisible(estado);
    percheo.setVisible(estado);
    alfombra.setVisible(estado);
    terraquio.setVisible(estado);
    estambre.setVisible(estado);
    gato.setVisible(estado);
    perro.setVisible(estado);
    hueso.setVisible(estado);
    llaves.setVisible(estado);
    tijera.setVisible(estado);
    libro.setVisible(estado);
    periodico.setVisible(estado);
    pecera.setVisible(estado);
    cuchara.setVisible(estado);
    manzana.setVisible(estado);
    mesa.setVisible(estado);
    tabrete.setVisible(estado);
    plato.setVisible(estado);
    florero.setVisible(estado);
    lampara.setVisible(estado);
    fosforo.setVisible(estado);
    monopoly.setVisible(estado);
    equipo.setVisible(estado);
    burbuja.setVisible(estado);
    camisa.setVisible(estado);
    cama.setVisible(estado);
    candado.setVisible(estado);
    carro.setVisible(estado);
    carta.setVisible(estado);
    casa.setVisible(estado);
    celular.setVisible(estado);
    cereal.setVisible(estado);
    colgate.setVisible(estado);
    escoba.setVisible(estado);
    flores.setVisible(estado);
    jabon.setVisible(estado);
    gancho.setVisible(estado);
    lavamanos.setVisible(estado);
    lavadora.setVisible(estado);
    perro.setVisible(estado);
    licuadora.setVisible(estado);
    navidad.setVisible(estado);
    oso.setVisible(estado);
    pantalon.setVisible(estado);
    pila.setVisible(estado);
    portatil.setVisible(estado);
    televisor.setVisible(estado);
    toalla.setVisible(estado);
    zapato.setVisible(estado);
    namepun.setVisible(estado);
    jButton1.setVisible(estado);
    jButton2.setVisible(estado);
    jButton3.setVisible(estado);
    jButton4.setVisible(estado);
    jButton5.setVisible(estado);
}

public void CleanBoton() {
    if (jButton1.getText().equals(nombre)) {
        jButton1.setText("Pila");
    } else if (jButton2.getText().equals(nombre)) {
        jButton2.setText("Gato");
    } else if (jButton3.getText().equals(nombre)) {
        jButton3.setText("Pantalon");
    } else if (jButton4.getText().equals(nombre)) {
        jButton4.setText("Lavadora");
    } else if (jButton5.getText().equals(nombre)) {
        jButton5.setText("Jabon");
    }
}

public void Mensaje(){
    if (jButton1.getText().equals(" ") || jButton2.getText().equals(" ") || jButton3.getText().equals(" ") || jButton4.getText().equals(" ") || jButton5.getText().equals(" ")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ganaste el Nivel 3", "Ganaste",  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Con el metodo para mostrar el mensaje te vale o necesitas saber como implantarlo?

Comment: Ese metodo lo implemento y no me sale el mensaje cuando los 5 botones , se pongan en blanco...Utilice esto pero no se porque no me da

Comment: public void Mensaje(){
    if (jButton1.getText().equals(" ") || jButton2.getText().equals(" ") || jButton3.getText().equals(" ") || jButton4.getText().equals(" ") || jButton5.getText().equals(" ")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ganaste el Nivel 3", "Ganaste",  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    }

Comment: Probaste mi respuesta te funciono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método para mostrar el mensaje es el siguiente:

```
public void comprueba(){
    if(btn1.getText().equals("")&&btn2.getText().equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "HAS GANADO");
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Este comprueba que dos botones estén en blanco, para comprobar 5 botones simplemente debes añadir al `if` mas condiciones con el operador `&&` ya que en tu método usabas `||` lo que hacia es que si uno de los botones tenia **un espacio** te mostraba el mensaje. Así que para añadir otro botón deberías añadir al  `if` lo siguiente:`&&btn3.getText().equals("")`

Comment: private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    estado = false;
    Inicio();
    Mensaje();
}

Comment: Ya lo hice pero igual no me muestra el mensaje si estoy llamando el metodo donde es? o lo llamo en los botones?

Comment: Cada vez que cambies un String a vacio deberias llamar al método para que compruebe si ha de mostrar el mensaje o no

Comment: Listo ya , Muchas Gracias

Comment: De nada un placer